Vulnerabilidades Next14
Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Next.js e logo após a criação do projeto, o comando npm install retorna várias vulnerabilidades, mesmo depois de executar npm audit fix e npm audit fix --force. Aqui está o que eu recebo no terminal:
added 19 packages, and audited 393 packages in 8s
147 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
8 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run npm audit for details.
Já tentei usar npm audit e npm outdated para identificar as dependências problemáticas e atualizá-las manualmente. Também adicionei overrides no package.json:
"overrides": {
"fast-glob": "3.3.2",
"micromatch": "4.0.5",
"glob": "^8.0.0",
"tailwindcss": "3.2.0",
"eslint-config-next": ">=10.2.1-canary.2"
}
Mesmo assim, o problema persiste.Estou usando a versão 20.17.0do Node.js e a versão 14.2.5 do Next.js. Como posso resolver essas vulnerabilidades ou estou fazendo algo errado com os overrides?

Por favor, não repita as perguntas. A publicação original está aqui, e as orientações a respeito dessa publicação estão disponíveis na caixa informacional do fechamento e comentários feitos na publicação original.
